# How can I improve the following grammar?

Tags: jquery, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to find out where I went wrong in the below code.

Flex input:

```
%{
        #include "jq.tab.h"
        void yyerror(char *);
%}
method          add|map|.. and other methods go here

%%

"/*"            { return CS; }

"*/"            { return CE; }

"jQuery"        {
                printf("%s is yytext\n", yytext);
                return *yytext;
                }

"args"          { return ARGUMENT; }

{method}        { return METHOD; }

[().\n]         { return *yytext; }

[ \t]+          { return WS; }

.               { return IGNORE; }

%%

int yywrap(void) {
        return 1;
}
```

Bison input:

```
%{
        #include <stdio.h>
        int yylex(void);
        void yyerror(char *);
%}

%token ARGUMENT METHOD IGNORE WS CS CE
%error-verbose

%%

stmts:
        stmt '\n'               { printf("A single stmt\n"); }
        | stmt '\n' stmts       { printf("Multi stmts\n"); }
        ;

stmt:
        jQuerycall                      { printf("A complete call ends here\n"); }
        | ignorechars                   { printf("Ignoring\n"); }
        | ignorechars WS jQuerycall     { printf("ignore+js\n"); }
        | jQuerycall WS ignorechars     { printf("js+ignore\n"); }
        | optionalws stmt optionalws
        | CS stmt CE                    { printf("comment\n"); }
        ;

jQuerycall:
        'jQuery' '(' ARGUMENT ')' '.' methodchain       { printf("args n methodchain\n"); }
        | 'jQuery' '(' ')' '.' methodchain              { printf("methodchain\n"); }
        | 'jQuery' '(' ARGUMENT ')'                     { printf("args\n"); }
        | 'jQuery' '(' ')'                              { printf("empty call\n"); }
        ;

methodchain:
        methodchain '.' methodcall
        | methodcall
        ;

methodcall:
        METHOD '(' ')'
        ;

ignorechars:
        IGNORE
        | IGNORE optionalws ignorechars
        ;

optionalws:
        | WS
        ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
        yyparse();
        return 0;
}
```

My aim is to recognize any jQuery call with all its elements, and ignore any other statement / string. Also ignore comments. Right now, this code makes many assumptions - like 'args' to be the only selector element inside jQuery().

### Edit

I am using the following input-output cases. Cases like 10 and 12 are the ones I'm trying to figure out:

```
> 1.input: statement\n output: Ignoring
> 
> 2.input: statement statement\n output: Ignoring
> 
> 3.input: statement statement statement\n output: Ignoring
> 
> 4.input: jQuery()\n output: jQuery is yytext empty call A complete call ends here
> 
> 5.input: jQuery(args)\n output: jQuery is yytext args A complete call ends here
> 
> 6.input: jQuery().add()\n output: jQuery is yytext methodchain A complete call ends here
> 
> 7.input: jQuery(args).add().map()\n output: jQuery is yytext args n methodchain A complete call ends here
> 
> 8.input: /*comment*/\n output: Ignoring comment
> 
> 9.input: /*jQuery()*/\n output: jQuery is yytext empty call A complete call ends here comment
> 
> 10.input: /* comment */\n output: syntax error, unexpected CE, expecting IGNORE
> 
> 11.input: var a = b\n output: Ignoring
> 
> 12.input: var a = jQuery(args)\n output: jQuery is yytext syntax error, unexpected 'jQuery', expecting IGNORE
```

Comment: If you want help, it would be useful for you to tell us what the symptoms of your problem are, and why you are having a hard time diagnosing the root cause.  Few of us are going to bother to read your code to try to guess what your symptom is.  If you're lazy, so are we.

Comment: @IraBaxter, 've edited the description to include the cases i'm concerned about.. Thank u:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your lex file, the rule:

```
"jQuery"        {
                printf("%s is yytext\n", yytext);
                return *yytext;
                }
```

returns the token `'j'` when it sees an input string of jQuery. Since your bison file never does anything with the token `'j'` this will generally give you a syntax error.

You need to add `JQUERY` to your `%token` declaration and have this lex rule return that.

**edit**

Usually a comment can appear anywhere in the program (between any two other tokens) and are completely ignored.  So the easiest way to deal with them is in the lexer:

```
%x comment
%%
"/*"           { BEGIN comment; }
<comment>.     ;
<comment>"*/"  { BEGIN 0; }
```

this will skip over comments (returning no tokens at all), so the grammar doesn't need to worry about them.  If you don't want to use a lexer start state, you could instead use the complex regex:

```
"/*"([^*]|\*+[^*/])*\*+"/"          ;
```

Comment: Okay, i fixed that. Also the rule ignorechars: IGNORE | IGNORE optionalws ignorechars had a right recursion. Fixed that too.. Yet to fix case 10

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give you a fix that will solve case 10, but there is a deeper problem.

Since case 8 gives you the results you expect, I infer that the input

```
/*comment*/
```

is recognized by the prouduction

```
stmt: CS stmt CE
```

Which is to say that the string "comment" is recognized as a `stmt`.  But when you add whitespace between `CS` and `stmt` the parse fails, which is your case 10.  You can patch this by rewriting your production as

```
stmt: CS optionalws stmt optionalws CE
```

But the deeper issue is that your parser can't recognize other comments, like

```
/* This is a remarkable remark, isn't it? */
```

and

```
/**
 * This is a multi-line comment.
 */
```